# How to add parameter to nginx query_string during redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect

I want to add one parameter to $query string. Now I have this config

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;

    return 301 http://test.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

But I want to add `test=1` into query. There are use cases:

```
http://example.com =>
    http://test.example.com?test=1

http://example.com/example =>
    http://test.example.com/example?test=1

http://example.com/example/?var=1 =>
    http://test.example.com/example/?var=1&test=1
```

I tried to split $request_uri to $uri and $query_param and got

```
return 301 http://test.example.com$uri$query_string;
```

But I cannot just add test=1 into this string. If I add `?test=1` so 
in the third case I will get `http://test.example.com/example/?var=1?test=1`. If I add `&test=1` there is in the first and second cases I will get `http://test.example.com&test=1` and `http://test.example.com/example&test=1`.

Now I check my $query_string by this rules:

```
if ($query_string ~ ^$) {
    return 301 http://test.example.com$uri?test=test;
}

if ($query_string ~ ^.+$) {
    return 301 http://test.example.com$uri?$query_string&test=test;
}
```

But I think there is more tidy decision for this task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `rewrite` instead of `return`. The `rewrite` directive already contains the logic to append additional query strings correctly.

For example:

```
rewrite ^ http://test.example.com$uri?test=1 permanent;
```

From the [manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite):

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the
>   previous request arguments are appended after them